# Finding minor performance hogs in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, debugging

To discover perfomance hogs in a specific method I often do something like this:

```
// Some line of code
LogTimeInterval();
// Some other line of code
LogTimeInterval();
// Some other line of code
LogTimeInterval();
```

Where `LogTimeInterval` is defined as:

```
void LogTimeInterval()
{
    static NSDate *_previousDate;
    static NSInteger _counter = 0;
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    if (!_previousDate) {
        _previousDate = date;
    }
    NSLog(@"LINE %d: %f", _counter++, [_previousDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date]);
    _previousDate = date;
}
```

This allows me to discover which lines of code are taking more time than necessary. However, it requires modifying the code and can be cumbersome when there is branching logic.

Is there a most efficient way to do this micro-level analysis for a specific method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try XCode's built-in Profiler. Among the tools it has, there is a time profiler. Check this [link for a nice tutorial on how to use it](http://blancer.com/tutorials/flex/78335/apple-profiling-tools-shark-is-out-instruments-is-in/)

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to say I only want to check this specific method?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the tutorial. You can attach the time profiler for a specific process only.

Comment: Also, you should probably check the disassembly view in the time profiler so you can see the output divided by methods. This tutorial mentions it: http://volonbolon.net/post/897931352/tuning-performance-with-instruments